# Contravariance not woking in Generic Custom Interface C#

Tags: c#, .net, covariance

Why Compiler is Complaining and not allowing contravariance at objCoAndContravariant.SampleMethod(new A()); when I specified in keyword for T2.
I have recently learned about contravariance that it reversed assignment compatibility so in keyword should allow the parent to be used for derived type.

```
class Mammal
{

}

class Person:Mammal
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Employee : Person
{

}   

class A
{

}

class B :A
{

}
interface ITestCoAndContraVariance<out T1,in T2>
{
    T1 SampleMethod(T2 arg);        
}

class ImplementCoAndContraVariance : ITestCoAndContraVariance<Person, B>
{
    public Person SampleMethod(B arg)
    {
        return new Employee();
    }
}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        //Custom Covariance and Contravariance in Interfaces
        ImplementCoAndContraVariance objCoAndContravariant = new ImplementCoAndContraVariance();
        objCoAndContravariant.SampleMethod(new A());

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: Why do you think you should be allowed to pass a `Tiger` to a method that accepts an `Person`?  If a method requires the input to be person, you can pass in an `Employee`, or a `Customer`, but not a `Tiger`.

Comment: Also your code doesn't use contravariance or covariance at all, it just leverages implicit conversions of the input and output, not implicit conversions of generic types that involve variance.

Comment: I have used in and out keyword. out keyword is for covariance and in keyword is for contravariance.

Comment: Yes, that means that you're *allowed* to use that interface for variance.  You're *allowed* to perform covariant conversions of the interface on the first parameter, and contravariant conversions on the second.  You don't actually *do* either of those things though, even though you're *allowed* to do those conversions.  All you've actually done is called the method on the class implementing the interface.

Comment: interface ITestCoAndContraVariance<out T1,in T2>
    {
        T1 SampleMethod(T2 arg);        
    }

    class ImplementCoAndContraVariance1 : ITestCoAndContraVariance<Person, B>
    {
        public Person SampleMethod(B arg)
        {
            return new Employee();
        }
    }

    class ImplementCoAndContraVariance2 : ITestCoAndContraVariance<Employee, A>
    {
        public Employee SampleMethod(A arg)
        {
            return new Employee();
        }
    }

Comment: I misunderstood the concept. Thanks Servy.